# create-react-app / react-router-dom v6 -- how can i establish a new site root?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to serve my app from a new site root, like `/v2`

so my nginx server serves up the app when navigating to `/v2` and i successfully get the HTML file to return, but when the app tries to call the other javascript files its requesting them without the `/v2` prefix

how can i either update the build folder to reflect a subfolder, or specify a new site root?

its a brand new app, so not much to show

```
const routes = [
  { path: '*', element: <PageNotFound /> },
  { path: '/', element: <Home />, errorElement: <ErrorPage /> }
]
return (
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
)
```

I can go to the index.html and add `/v2` in front of a few of the paths and they will load, but the `*.js` files do not load correctly and do not show up with the prefix on page load

this is the `react-scripts build` output:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/v2/favicon.ico" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
  <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/v2/logo192.png" />
  <link rel="manifest" href="/v2/manifest.json" />
  <title>Loading ...</title>
  <script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.1310c545.js"></script>
</head>

<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `"homepage": "/v2",` to your package.json and leave the index.html file alone

see:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#building-for-relative-paths

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration